# Symfony Doctrine: Search in simple_array

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I got values stored in my database column field as `value1,value2,value3,value4`, so a `simple_array` column.

So i'm using Doctrine to make a search using this:

```
$searchQuery = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Ads')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere("p.vals <= :value2")
        ->setParameter('value2',  $request->query->get('value2'));
        ->orderBy("p.creationtime", 'DESC');
```

So expecting `value2` is in the 2nd position of a simple array like `value1,value2,value3`, how can i ask QueryBuilder to select the second value in the string?

I think this query try to get all the values in `p.vals`, results are not right, shound select just one.

How can I select eg. the 2nd value in `p.vals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot access nth item of an array column using pure Mysql since the data is serialized, in order to do it I'd create a simple function

```
public function getItemFromArray(array $array, $index)
{
    return isset($array[$index]) ? $array[$index] : null;
}
```

And if you want to find item with condition use

```
array_filter()
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand, I'm not trying to convert the string to array, I just need to tell Doctrine's Query Builder to select a value positioned in a determined index and search the value inside.

Comment: You cant access nth value of an array in query builder, the data in p.vals is a serialized string(not an array) you can't archieve it using querybuilder / sql php code needs to be applied

Comment: Understood, so how can be applied if I need to make a search query? Could you provide a runnable example using my code?

Comment: The thing is you can't really make a search query with simple_array type, you would need to specify those values in a separate entity and add @ManyToOne relation, then you can access the "valueN" directly if you need a query not a code side solution

Comment: Sorry to say that your database design is insufficient as you need to query on an array which is multiple data inside one column. You should add a OneToMany related entity which will add a new table in your database. That really solves your problem!